# File corrupted when using send_file() from flask, data from pymongo gridfs

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

Well my English is not good, and the title may looks weird.

Anyway, I'm now using flask to build a website that can store files, and mongodb is the database.

The file upload, document insert functions have no problems, the weird thing is that the file sent from flask `send_file()` was truncated for no reasons. Here's my code

```py
from flask import ..., send_file, ...
import pymongo
import gridfs

#...

@app.route("/record/download/<record_id>")
def api_softwares_record_download(record_id):
    try:
        #...
        file = files_gridfs.find_one({"_id": record_id})
        file_ext = filetype.guess_extension(file.read(2048))
        filename = "{}-{}{}".format(
            app["name"],
            record["version"],
            ".{}".format(file_ext) if file_ext else "",
        )
        response = send_file(file, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=filename)
        return response
    except ...
```

The original image file, for example, is 553KB. But the response body returns 549.61KB, and the image was broken. But if I just directly write the file to my disk

```py
#...
with open('test.png', 'wb+') as file:
    file.write(files_gridfs.find_one({"_id": record_id}).read())
```

The image file size is 553KB and the image is readable.

When I compare the two files with VS Code's text editor, I found that the correct file starts with `�PNG`, but the corrupted file starts with `�ϟ8���>�L�y`

[search the corrupted file head in the correct file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsXcn.png)

And I tried to use `Blob` object and download it from the browser. No difference.

Is there any wrong with my code or I misused `send_file()`? Or should I use `flask_pymongo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And it's interesting that I have found what is wrong with my code.

This is how I solved it

```
...file.read(2048)
file.seek(0)
...
file.read(2048)
file.seek(0)
...
response = send_file(file, ...)
return response
```

And here's why:

For some reasons, I use `filetype` to detect the file's extension name and mime type, so I sent 2048B to `filetype` for detection.

```py
file_ext = filetype.guess_extension(file.read(2048))
file_mime = filetype.guess_mime(file.read(2048)) #this line wasn't copied in my question. My fault.
```

And I have just learned from the [pymongo API](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/gridfs/grid_file.html#gridfs.grid_file.GridOut.seek) that python (or `pymongo` or `gridfs`, completely unknown to this before) reads file by using a cursor. When I try to find the cursor's position using `file.seek()`, it returns `4096`. So when I call `file.read()` again in `send_file()`, the cursor reads from 4096B away to the file head. 549+4=553, and here's the problem.

Finally I set the cursor to position 0 after every `read()` operation, and it returns the correct file.

Hope this can help if you made the same mistake just like me.